# How do I apply an epsilon delta proof to the following problem?

Tags: limits, continuity

Any help in solving the following problem would be greatly appreciated:

> Let $f, g_1, g_2$ be functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$, with
>   $g_1(x) \leq f(x) \leq  g_2(x)$, for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Suppose
>   that, for some $p \in \mathbb R$, we have $\lim_{x \rightarrow p}
> g_1(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow p} g_2(x) = c$. Show that $ \lim_{x\rightarrow p} f(x) = c,$
>    as well.

I've spent hours on it and haven't come up with anything worth posting.

Comment: What do you mean by $\lim_{x \rightarrow p}
> g_1(x) $?

Comment: $\lim_{x \rightarrow p}
> c$ ?

Comment: @sizz: I suspect that the $>$ is just a typo.

Comment: isn't it the "squeeze theorem" for limits?if $g_1$ and $g_2$ have limit equal $c$ then $f$ has limit equal $c$?

Comment: @Charlie, in that case http://web.mit.edu/wwmath/calculus/limits/squeeze.html

Comment: @sizz $\blacksquare$

Comment: This had been copied from an email I think or a forum. The weird > signs were at the beginning of each line. I have removed them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Let $\epsilon>0$. There are real numbers $\delta_1,\delta_2>0$ such that $$|g_1(x)-c|<\frac{\epsilon}2\quad\text{whenever}\quad 0<|x-p|<\delta_1$$ and $$|g_2(x)-c|<\frac{\epsilon}2\quad\text{whenever}\quad 0<|x-p|<\delta_2\;.$$

Now show that

$$|f(x)-c|<\epsilon\quad\text{whenever}\quad 0<|x-p|<\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}\;.$$

Comment: @BrainMScott Thank you! The procedure seems simple when one examines it.

Comment: @Neil: You’re welcome. Experience helps in seeing where to start, but I agree that the basic idea isn’t hard.